# I need an ID to be inserted in a sub-entity when I insert it into the parent table

Tags: mysql

So I have 3 tables that are still in the logical ERD state. Devices, HearingDevices and Vision Devices. Hearing and Vision devices are derived from the Device entity.

I'm just pondering, is there any way I can create a entry where when I enter a device with ID 001 in the device entity, it will replicate in my two sub entities i.e. hearing and vision device entities.

Even if thats not possible. How would I display the corresponding hearing or vision device when I print out the device information ( I know you can use a simple embedded select statement but I'm looking for alternative options )

My code is down below,

```
CREATE TABLE Device (
   deviceCatalogID varchar(5),
   deviceCatalogName varchar(20),
   deviceDescription varchar(300),
   availabilityStatus boolean,

   CONSTRAINT pk_device_catalogID PRIMARY KEY (deviceCatalogID)
 );
```

```
 CREATE TABLE Visual_Device (
   deviceCatalogID varchar(5),
   frBrand varchar(20),
   frModel varchar(20),
   lensSerialN varchar(20),
   lensVisionType varchar(20),
   lensTint set('1','2','3'),
   lensThinnessLevel set('1','2','3'),

   CONSTRAINT pk_visionDevice_catalogID PRIMARY KEY (deviceCatalogID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_visualDevice_catalogID FOREIGN KEY (deviceCatalogID) references device(deviceCatalogID)
 );
```

```
 CREATE TABLE Hearing_Device (
   deviceCatalogID varchar(5),
   hdMake varchar(20),
   hdModel varchar(20),

   CONSTRAINT pk_hearingDevice_catalogID PRIMARY KEY (deviceCatalogID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_hearingDevice_catalogID FOREIGN KEY (deviceCatalogID) references device(deviceCatalogID)
 );
```

Comment: And while this magic replication is taking place, what would it place in the other columns that dont exist in the `Device` table ??

Comment: Somehow the other direction makes more sense to me. Insert a record into `visual_device` also creates a record in `device` (and analog for `hearing_device`). Or are all devices hearing and visual devices at the same time?

Comment: @RiggsFolly lol love the sass but I believe that was implied in my question when I said i was simply "Pondering"

Comment: @stickybit I suppose it does. But I believe either way, it would require me to add the data to the device entity at the same time as the visual or hearing device ?

Comment: Yea, sorry. That gets me in trouble from time to time :)

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb tip is "NEVER use the SET data type".

Comment: @Strawberry why is that?? Also would enum be a better option

Comment: It's antithetical to the notion of normalisation, which underpins relational databases; It's limited to 64 elements; And it's ability to utilise indexes is limited. No. Don't use ENUM either, but I'll forgive you if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about database triggers:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

You can replicate entries in devive to the other two tables this way:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/VAfRc5GA4sjsV3ZYpiVwq/0

Comment: So I'm assuming as I enter the ID I can enter that itself and the remaining values. And Im also assuming that i can enter values into the Other tables at the same time using an embedded statement somewhere?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if i got your question, but you can insert values in the derived tables with the 2 nested insert statements. If you want to reference the row that was just inserted into Device use the "NEW" keyword to reference the values of the newly added row.

Comment: Thanks Roger. Sorry my question wasn't clear but it was the answer I somewhat expected. I will definitely use this. Thank you !